# How to make indexing of values in column within a group defined by other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B2",
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"), operation = c("open",
"open", "close", "", "open", "close", "", "open", "open", "open",
"close", "upload", "open", "close", "open", "close")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-16L))
```

```
ID      operation
A1       open
A1       open
A1       close
A1       
A1       open
A1       close
B2      
B2       open
B2       open
B2       open
B2       close
B2       upload
B2       open
B2       close
B2       open
B2       close
```

I wanted to add index for each bundle of "open" and "close" in column operation. So for each row between open and close must have same index. So desired result is:

```
ID      operation    index
A1       open         1
A1       open         1
A1       close        1
A1       
A1       open         2
A1       close        2
B2      
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       close        3
B2       upload
B2       open         4
B2       close        4
B2       open         5
B2       close        5
```

I did it like this:

```
rank <- df$operation == "close" & !is.na(df$operation)
df$index <- cumsum(c(1, rank[-length(rank)]))
df$index[!df$operation %in% c("open", "close")] <- NA
```

Now I want to make this indexing within each ID. So for each ID indexing starts from scratch. So desired result is:

```
ID      operation    index
A1       open         1
A1       open         1
A1       close        1
A1       
A1       open         2
A1       close        2
B2      
B2       open         1
B2       open         1
B2       open         1
B2       close        1
B2       upload
B2       open         2
B2       close        2
B2       open         3
B2       close        3
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[!is.na(index), index := rleid(index), by = .(ID)]
df
#     ID operation index
#  1: A1      open     1
#  2: A1      open     1
#  3: A1     close     1
#  4: A1              NA
#  5: A1      open     2
#  6: A1     close     2
#  7: B2              NA
#  8: B2      open     1
#  9: B2      open     1
# 10: B2      open     1
# 11: B2     close     1
# 12: B2    upload    NA
# 13: B2      open     2
# 14: B2     close     2
# 15: B2      open     3
# 16: B2     close     3
```

---

There are built-in R functions named `dt` or `df`. Althought R can discriminate variables from functions, It's better to use other names.